Cutom Loss Function in Keras - Multi-task Learning
How can I create the following custom loss function for the multi-task learning NN model shown below. The trick here is I have two tasks.

task_weight1 = task_loss1 / (task_loss1 + task_loss2)
task_weight2 = task_loss2 / (task_loss1 + task_loss2)
loss = task_weight1 \* task_loss1 + task_weight2 \* task_loss2

from sklearn.metrics import r2_score, mean_absolute_error, mean_squared_error import seaborn as sns import matplotlib.pyplot as plt from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix from keras.models import Model from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Concatenate, Dropout from keras.optimizers import Adam from keras.metrics import Precision, Recall import numpy as np from keras.regularizers import l2

Define the shared input layer

input_layer = Input(shape=(input_data.shape[1],))

Define the shared hidden layers

shared_hidden_layer_1 = Dense(200, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(5e-4))(input_layer) shared_hidden_layer_1 = BatchNormalization()(shared_hidden_layer_1) shared_hidden_layer_1 = Dense(200, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(5e-4))(shared_hidden_layer_1) shared_hidden_layer_1 = BatchNormalization()(shared_hidden_layer_1) shared_hidden_layer_1 = Dense(200, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(5e-4))(shared_hidden_layer_1) shared_hidden_layer_1 = BatchNormalization()(shared_hidden_layer_1)

Define the Outputs

task1_output = Dense(5, activation="softmax", name='task1_output')(shared_hidden_layer_1) task2_output = Dense(4, activation="softmax", name='task2_output')(shared_hidden_layer_1)

Define the model with multiple outputs

model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=[task1_output, task2_output])

Define a specific learning rate

learning_rate = 3e-4

Instantiate an optimizer with the desired learning rate

optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)

Compile the model

model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss = keras.losses.CategoricalFocalCrossentropy(), metrics= ['accuracy'])


